# Fedora 39 machine cannot resolve Fedora domain, but can resolve any other site fine

Tags: fedora, dns, dnf

I have two machines, one running Windows 11 and other with Fedora 39. The windows machine can access any site, no issues. I've been using the Fedora machine for weeks and it was fine, but today I tried running `sudo dnf update` and it said `couldn't resolve hostname for mirrors.fedoraproject.org`. I tried opening fedoraproject.org on my Fedora machine using Firefox, and it said "having trouble finding this site". Same for any other fedora site. However I tried google, NPR, reddit, etc, and they all worked fine.

I then tried on my windows machine, and it could access any site just fine, even fedoraproject.org sites.

So it appears that something on my fedora machine is preventing me from resolving the fedoraproject.org domain name, and just on that machine. What gives?

`ping fedoraproject.org` on my Fedora machine gives nothing. `ping google.com` works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Unplugged and re-plugged the ethernet on my fedora machine and now everything works again.

(for reference, I had shutdown and restarted, but that didn't help. And when it wasn't working, it was just fedoraproject.org that wasn't working; every other site was fine)